# Why does Python's getrandbits() never produce negative numbers?

Tags: python, random

I have a python script that uses both random.Random and random.SystemRandom.
I use the SystemRandom object to seed the Random object. The values from the Random object are used in a simulation and the seed value is printed for the user to reproduce the results.

However, I've noticed that with either of them, if I call getrandbits(64), it never displays the number as negative. It's always a positive integer.

I would expect, given randomness, that close to 50% of the time it would produce a negative value (by setting the left-most bit to 1).

Why are my expectations incorrect?

My implementation:

```
sr = random.SystemRandom()
seed = sr.getrandbits(64)
seedgen = random.Random(seed)
...
seedgen.getrandbits(64)
```

Comment: How big is a C `long` on your system?

Comment: @MadPhysicist 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python int's aren't limited to 64 bits. They get promoted to Python longs (arbitrary precision)

Comment: I see in the interactive prompt, they are indeed appended with L.  So, does that mean that instead of ever having a negative value, the precision just increases so it always remains positive?

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in integers become longs (arbitrary precision integers) if they are larger than 64-bits. You can easily compute `2**150` in Python and get the result `1427247692705959881058285969449495136382746624L` (the `L` suffix signifies that the type is a Python long, which has unlimited precision).

Comment: The distinction between `int` and `long` is better hidden in Python3

Comment: However, since I'm only generating a 64-bit number, I would expect the precision to be exactly 64bits. I am seeing the -L suffix in the interactive prompt. It sounds like the arbitrary precision doesn't allow for negative values unless a flag is set.

Comment: @Anro The normal ints are 64-bit *signed* types, but the value generated by `getrandbits()` is always positive. So if you try to generate more than 63 bits (max positive value that can be held in a signed 64-bit integer), it will be promoted to a Python long.